Using Telegram API - Telegraf - By trying to accept users' join requests with promoteChatMember() error: Bad Request: bots can't add new chat members
So my telegram bot is in this supergroup (private group) and users' must request to join, and an admin must accept their request.
Searching online, the only solution I saw was using promoteChatMember(), however I get this error:
  response: {
    ok: false,
    error_code: 400,
    description: "Bad Request: bots can't add new chat members"
  },
  on: {
    method: 'promoteChatMember',
    payload: { chat_id: (MY_GROUP), user_id: (MY_USERID) }
  }

Is there at least any way, if this one isn't possible, to accept user join requests with my bot?
I made sure that the IDs are both correct, but to no luck. I have no idea what to do because I can't see this issue anywhere on the internet (only 1-2 random topics that have no solution) and I can't find any Telegram Bot Devs communities.
My telegram bot has all permission settings I can give it with BotFather on checked, and also has every admin right in my private supergroup. I also made sure to remove and add the bot again just to make sure everything is refreshed in the group, but to no luck.

Fixed this using the direct API, telegraf is not fully updated.
Fetch an URL and use this method.
